# Problem attaching stylesheet to CKEditor

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I've got a config.js file that looks like:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  config.stylesSet = 'custom:/themes/custom.js';
  config.contentsCss = '/assets/css/master.css';
};
```

I can see the styles that I've defined in my custom.js in CKEditor's styles dropdown, but when I apply them to elements in the WYSIWYG editor, the styles don't show in the editor, but they do when the entry is published. Is there something else I'm missing? :?

Comment: Are you pointing `config.contentsCss` at the same css you're using on the main site? I mean, with layout rules and other stuff? If so, try checking selectors for your text styles—maybe that rules don't apply inside CKEditor area. (In my case, with pretty complex rules in master stylesheet, it was necessary to create a separate css file with only typography-related styles for this to work.)

Comment: Tried adding a stylesheet just for the editor styles with the same result.

Comment: What browser are you're using? Maybe your problem is related to MIME types, check this thread: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=53687&sid=f957ae9094ba1c575bd1df5e5f6bdf8d#p53687

Comment: Yeah, saw that thread already but because I've been testing in Chrome, didn't think it was relevant. However I tried out the proposed solution and it hasn't changed anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I believe that path is relevant to the html (or php) file displaying the page and not the js file.

I use CKEditor and had to do this with images but not css. let me know if it works.

Comment: The path to the css file is relative to the server root, not the CKEditor config file.